# Open document file with Google Docs, Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-drive-api, document, google-docs-api

I just want to integrate the google docs api to my project to open uploaded documents! I dont want Google Drive, the files are already uploaded on my server. I don't want to edit them or change anything, so it should be READONLY... I spent hours on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs, I tried a couple of things but I couldn't find what I want!

for the pdf files, I used HTML5 to open them and it worked perfectly, but I couldn't find a way  to open World documents with HTML5 object tag... Any idea how to do it? Thank you

Visual Studio 2012 - ASP.NET MVC 4

Answer (score 1):

Use an iframe to embed `File.embedLink`, documented on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource